# Hide WooCommerce thank you page order details

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

After placing an order in my WooCommerce store the customer gets redirected to a thank you (order-received) page.

I want to hide all of the details generated by WooCommerce on that page so that it only shows the custom content I have displayed at the top of the page.

I have tried using some custom CSS `display:none;` but there are not any appropriate selectors to select.

How do I hide the:

1. Order details
2. Customer details
3. Billing address
4. Order number
5. date
6. total
7. payment method

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be done by many ways one of the way is by using [WooCommerce template override](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Copy this file

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php
```

and paste it into your active theme directory something like this

```
/wp-content/themes/activetheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php
```

And remove this

```
<ul class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">
    <li class="order">
        <?php _e( 'Order Number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
    </li>
    <li class="date">
        <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></strong>
    </li>
    <li class="total">
        <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
    </li>
    <?php if ( $order->payment_method_title ) : ?>
    <li class="method">
        <?php _e( 'Payment Method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo $order->payment_method_title; ?></strong>
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and also remove this

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->payment_method, $order->id ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->id ); ?>
```

So your final `thankyou.php` will look like this.

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
{
    exit;
}
if ($order) :
    ?>
    <?php if ($order->has_status('failed')) : ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php _e('Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again.', 'woocommerce'); ?></p>
        <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($order->get_checkout_payment_url()); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e('Pay', 'woocommerce') ?></a>
            <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_page_permalink('myaccount')); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e('My Account', 'woocommerce'); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __('Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce'), $order); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __('Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce'), null); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent, Thanks!

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but for future readers: removing the `woocommerce_thankyou` hooks isn't a great idea. There may be all kinds of integrations that rely on that hook being in place. Use `remove_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_order_details_table', 10);` instead.

Comment: indextwo's answer needs to be an actual answer so it can get the upvotes it deserves.

Comment: You can also use `add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', '__return_empty_string' );` to remove the Thank You sentence at the top.